# BroadcastReceiver doesn't work

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I added receiver in manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".PackageReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            <data android:scheme="package"/>
        </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

And this is my BroadcastReceiver

```
public class PackageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.e("noti", "sucess");
    //Start Notification Service
    Intent i = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
    context.startService(i);
}}
```

..

When I install this package, It's didn't work...

This package don't have activity.(only service and resource)

Is this a problem?

Then..

How to call BroadcastReceiver in this package without activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question that is asked a lot.

Check out this [`Commonsware` blog](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html).

`Starting with 3.1 when applications are installed they are in a “stopped” state so they will not be able to run until the user explicitly launches them. Pressing Force Stop will return them to this state.`

There needs to be an active component in your application that the user can start. When your activity gets started, your `BroadcastReceiver` will be registered.

Answer (score 0):

You have just declared and implemented a BroadcastReceiver, but you haven't started it yet, you need an entry point to start your receiver ( activity or service )

here is the code to register

```
PackageReceiver packageReceiver= new PackageReceiver(this);
registerReceiver( packageReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"));
```

Comment: As there is no straigh forward way, check out the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909683/launch-android-application-without-main-activity-and-start-service-on-launching