# How to add a service in the Android framework?

Tags: android, service

I hope to add a background service in Android. I know how to do this by developing an app and starting the service from the app.

However, I want to include the service in the rom. Since no UI is needed, I don't want to write an app for it and include the app. Instead, I want to add the stand alone app.

Also, this is not a system service, as it won't expose any interface to other apps. It just does some performance measurements in the background.

I hope to know how I can implement this and where I should put the code in the framework. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how to do this. I just need to write this as an app without any activity. Further details can be checked at [1] and [2].

[1] https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/PFEnMXldvB8
[2] [Launch Android application without main Activity and start Service on launching application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909683/launch-android-application-without-main-activity-and-start-service-on-launching)