# Android app without icon : deleting catrgory launcher gives error

Tags: android

I want to create an Android app as service. No activity no icon. When I hit the run button from android studio the Android service should be shown in the logs. But when I am deleting following line of code to prevent showing app icon , the app doesn't run and shows error. How to resolve this. I am a beginner in android. Any piece of code for example is welcomed.

`<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`

Error it shows as follows

```
Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
Error while Launching activity.
```

Service class is as follows

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "FirstService started");
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "FirstService destroyed");
}
```

Comment: that is not possible because to run the a service in background you need to run/open the app atleast once.

Comment: you can extend your application From widget or also you can use Service as alternate

Answer (score 0):

You must have a launcher activity in your `manifest` file.

> No activity no icon - **NOT POSSIBLE**

You can have your purpose served by installing your application first and then start the service and when the service is started, call `finish()` on your `Activity`

You can have a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10909723/3145960) for clearer idea.