# Is it possible to create standalone Broadcastreceiver in android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I'm creating a service called WifiMonitoring which will turn off Wifi when the connection is lost. I'm using a broadcastreceiver to receive the intent, which in-turn call the service. But now I'm stuck. Can I disable the wifi on receiving the intent in the OnReceive() method in the broadcastreceiver itself ? Is that possible to create a standalone broadcastreceive in android?

Comment: see here, maybe it helps:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909683/launch-android-application-without-main-activity-and-start-service-on-launching

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible to change wifi from broad cast receiver...Give the following permissions to your App's Manifest file
    ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, 
    CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
And add the following code within the broadcast receiver

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thank u for the reply pal. But my app does not have any activity. Is that possible then? If yes then how do i install it?

Comment: yes it is possible, create a separate broadcast receiver class and call it in service

Answer (score 0):

Unless your app is a system app, you must have at least one `Activity` and the user must explicitly start your app at least once. Otherwise your app will always be in the "stopped state" and it will never receive the broadcast `Intent`s.