# how to create a service without showing in application catalog?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Want to create Android Service, once installed on phone. It should not be shown in application catalog which shows list of application installed on Phone. After Google Search found following two links.

But Problem with above link solution:
 It shows application installed in application catalog.

Question:
        Is there any way to create android service like Keyboard application ( IME :Input Method Editor  ). which is not shown in application catalog.

Can Someone tell me, how can i create service application without showing it on installed application catalog.

[Can an Android app be made without an activity?](https://www.quora.com/Can-an-Android-app-be-made-without-an-activity)

[Launch Android application without main Activity and start Service on launching application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909683/launch-android-application-without-main-activity-and-start-service-on-launching)

Comment: If it is not listed, then how do users uninstall your app?

Comment: It can be uninstalled by going to app in settings