# Is it possible to make an apk with no activity?

Tags: android, apk

Can I make an apk that only has a service?

I'm trying to make a long running service that sits in the back and updates a database. No UI.

I always thought that a Service had to be bootstrapped to an Activity in order to make an APK but is that true?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch Android application without main Activity and start Service on launching application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909683/launch-android-application-without-main-activity-and-start-service-on-launching)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate since it is related to a complete "app" as opposed to the "concept" of starting a service where the app may not be active but still have one or more activities...

Comment: Why don't you just make an apk without a service and find out.  You could've been done you've had 10 hours.

Comment: What's the big deal a activity without UI minus 1 again If I could

Comment: There are differences between an Activity and a Service that extend beyond the UI. That's probably why they only let you minus once :)

Answer (score 2):

You can, but you might have problems. Google prohibits an app from starting an Activity with an "action" - something from the user.

See this post: [How to start android service on installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127044/how-to-start-android-service-on-installation)

It may be possible to capture a user action not related to "your" activity, as suggested in that post and like this:

[Can I start a service without activity or receiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468006/can-i-start-a-service-without-activity-or-receiver)

However, I'm pretty sure that the last time I checked, the "start service" portion of Android required a user-visible activity to be displayed. Otherwise, malicious activities may occur without the user recognizing that an app was even installed or acknowledged.